# login not working properly in Login state update not re-rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm integrating an `axios` login API for my app. `app.js` is the parent component,`login.js` is the child.

The idea was to declare a state `isAuthenticated` with `false` as defaultvalue. and then in the `app.js` with an `if-else` render all the components only if `isAuthenticated` is `true`. In `else` the `login` component will be displayed. `isAuthenticated` will be set to `true` after successfull login. but after successfull login login `isAuthenticated` is updated to `true` but the `if` part is not getting rendered. it just shows the login. shouldn't the state update initiate a re-render?

I'm just starting on React. What am I doing wrong guys. Any help would be much appreciated.

on clicking login post api the response is 200 ok. I'm using an if to change the isAuthenticated in the parent app.js. isAuthenticated is set to false by default. all works okay but the if statement in app.js that checks this.state.isAuthenticated is not re-rendering.

this is the main component App.js

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state= {
      isAuthenticated:false,
    }
  }
  setAuth=this.setAuth.bind(this);
  Logout=this.Logout.bind(this);
  setAuth(auth){
    console.log('setauth',auth);
    this.state.isAuthenticated=true;
    console.log('isauth',this.state.isAuthenticated)
    //this.forceUpdate()
  }
  Logout(){
    this.setState({isAuthenticated:false});
    message.success('Logout Successful');
  }

  render() {
  console.log(this.state.isAuthenticated,"before if");
  if(this.state.isAuthenticated) { 
  return( 
    <div> 
-------------content--------------
    </div>
    )} return (
      <WrappedLogin setAuth={this.setAuth}/>
    );
  }
}
```

this is the child component

```
class Login extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state= {
      loginStatus:[],
    }
  }
  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.form.validateFields((err, values) => {
      if (!err) {
        console.log(' values of form: ',values );
        axios.post('http://192.168.137.1:8000/user/login/',values)
        .then(res => {
          console.log(res);
          console.log(res.data.status);

        if (res.data.status==200)
                  {this.props.setAuth(true)
                    console.log('if');}
        else
                  console.log('password incorrect');})
render() {
return (
);
  }
}
const WrappedLogin = Form.create({ name: 'normal_login' })(Login);
export default WrappedLogin;
```

this is what I'm getting on console

```
values of form:  {outlook_id: "aashik1", password: "Be$t^197901*"}
{data: {…}, status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}
200
setauth true
isauth true
if
```

Comment: `setAuth=this.setAuth.bind(this);` should be inside constructor; use `this.setState({ isAuthenticated: true });` instead of `this.state.isAuthenticated = true;` in setAuth function for re-render.

Comment: `this.setState({ isAuthenticated: true });` did it. no difference.
`setAuth=this.setAuth.bind(this);` i put it inside the constructor but its showing error.

`class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state= {
      isAuthenticated:true,
    }
  setAuth=this.setAuth.bind(this);
  
  }`

Comment: `this.setAuth=this.setAuth.bind(this);` instead of `setAuth=this.setAuth.bind(this);`

Comment: @tarzenchugh Thanks!!! it's working. But I do have a few concerns. do you think the method I used is the correct method to do this. because now if the user clicks the browser refresh button, it automatically logs out.

Comment: also all the other api calls have slowed down considerably.

Comment: Usually for login functionality JWT token, OAuth tokens are used that are received from post api call. We store those token in local storage so on refresh we have a way to maintain session. Refer to [this link](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/04/06/react-jwt-authentication-tutorial-example) more explanation

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't modify state directly, it will not re-render your component. Instead of

```
this.state.isAuthenticated = true;
```

you should write

```
this.setState({ isAuthenticated: true });
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly